# Cannot install a specific versions of rails (on MacOs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure if this is related to the OS or version of Mac (Monterey) that I'm using. However here's the sequence of events as listed below. The gem seems to be the version I want (6.0.5) however `rails -v` keeps giving me the latest (7.0.3) which is not what I want!

```
❯ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.


❯ sudo gem install rails -v 6.0.5
Successfully installed rails-6.0.5
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.5
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

❯ rbenv rehash

❯ rails -v
Rails 7.0.3

❯ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (6.0.5)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
sprockets-rails (3.4.2)

❯ rbenv versions
  system
  2.6.5
  2.7.0
* 2.7.5 (set by /Users/jeffsaremi/.rbenv/version)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the rails new command like..

```
rails _6.0.5_ new myapp
```

creating a new rails app with the specified version.

Or you can try..

Check which versions you have installed with

```
gem list rails
```

and uninstall the versions you do not want used with

```
gem uninstall rails -v '7.0.3'
```

and replace 7.0.3 with whichever version you do not want used, until you only have your desired version installed. I believe that would be the best way to have it always generate on that version without specifying the version as shown in the first example.

Comment: Is this the right way of doing this? Or is this a workaround? I don't want to have to so this each time I issue a rails command. I have to remember to provide an extra argument. I have to remember the syntax. I have to remember the version I needed.

Comment: @JeffSaremi i updated my answer, hope that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think that version is detected. I have a listing for gem list in my original post. If you notice there is actually no rails version 7.0.3 in the list. If I run your commands I get: ```
❯ gem uninstall rails -v '7.0.3'
Gem 'rails' is not installed

❯ sudo gem uninstall rails -v '7.0.3'
Password:
Gem 'rails' is not installed```

Comment: Ah yeah I see that now, I'd assume it just automatically installs the latest version. Sorry, not too sure on this one. I would just use the first example for now, but I'm sure there's a workaround I am not aware of!